# SetIgnoreDebugger not working on watchdog ANR, Cannot debug android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, watchdog

I have a Xamarin Forms app running google maps.
On my android 11 device it crashes and I have no idea why there is no error it just crashes or shows the not responding error, So I installed the Watchdog anr from a nugut package to try and detect the issue
[1]: https://github.com/nwestfall/Xamarin.ANRWatchDog
and initialised it with new ANRWatchDog().SetIgnoreDebugger(true).Start(); in oncreate() in the mainactivity.cs file
I get the message in the device log 'An ANR was detected but ignored because the debugger is connected (you can prevent this with setIgnoreDebugger(true))

Am I using this iscorrectely as my understanding is the way I initialised it shouold prevent this message.

Or is there another way I should be using it or another way I can find this error that is causing the crashes.

Thank you

Comment: From your description, you mean that installing Watchdog cause your project crash? If you don't use Watchdog, is there any problem?

Comment: Sorry @CherryBu-MSFT I have updated the OP to be more clear. The app was crashing so i installed Watchdog

Comment: You can target other android device (for example Android 8.1 or other) to test, if crash still, you can download the [doc map sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map) to test.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me, seems like a bug - needs diving into sources